Rev, 13:15 - Who is the beast here, but more specifically ... Who is it's "image" that *speaks* and *causes* non "marked" worshipers to be killed?
I am quite aware of the following Q: Second beast or the image that will force the people to receive a mark on their hands or forehead in Revelation 13:15-16? ... but this does not speak to the death of those who do not take the mark. Whereas, I have always been mystified by what seemingly amounts to a truly alarming outcome for people's non worship of the image of the beast. I, myself, am more inclined to believe the killings to be historical, NOT futuristic. Consequently, I would prefer any possible forthcoming answers to concentrate on past fulfillment. This does not mean that members should not post with regard to a futuristic rending, if so inclined.
Rev, 13:15 (NASB)

And there was given to him to give breath to the image of the beast, that the image of the beast might even speak and cause as many as do not worship the image of the beast to be killed.

For further consideration, in deference to the already linked question, one should also note the subsequent verse:
Rev, 13:16 (NASB)

And he causes all, the small and the great, and the rich and the poor, and the free men and the slaves, to be given a mark on their right hand, or on their forehead ...

NB
I may yet answer this Q. myself, although comments that I have since  posted, under answers already given, already speak somewhat to what I would have to say, which may already appear to be "opinion based" but then again ....

Not my downvote BTW.

A key point to understand why those who do NOT have the beast's mark are killed, is that only those who belong to Jesus will never worship Satan's beastly agents on earth; they are attacked by those demonic agents.
To grasp what Revelation 13:15 signifies, let me set the historic scene as detailed in the book I will quote from later. The sea beast has been in existence even before Daniel's visions, continuing till the Roman empire, where Daniel's visions stopped. The Roman empire suffered the deadly wound (at Christ's death and resurrection), but has wondrously revived with multiple horns / diadems (= worldly, political facets). This sea-beast is allowed to continue for a symbolic 42 months, persecuting and overcoming the saints, even till now. Only some Christians seem to know that this persecution has become worse this century than ever it was at any previous time in history. But in the lead-up to Christ's return, the full fury of the invisible red dragon (who is pulling the strings of his earthly agents) will be felt by Christians who refuse to bow.
This is when the 2nd beast arises - appearing to be oh, so religious and lamb-like, but it also blasphemes God by deceiving the world into a false worship with signs (Rev. 13:13), killing those who do not worship the image of the 1st beast, and who therefore do not have its mark (Rev. 13:16). The 1st beast is glorified by the 2nd beast, who causes this image of the 1st beast to arise.
Although all attempts to unravel these mysteries could be called personal opinions (or, rather, interpretations), I now quote from a 614-page book expounding the whole of the book of Revelation, but sticking to the texts in question:

"The rise of the second beast, followed by the endorsement of
world-wide religion, is called 'him, whose coming is after the working
of Satan with all power and signs and lying wonders, and with all
deceivableness of unrighteousness in them that perish; because they
received not the love of the truth, that they might be saved. And for
this cause God shall send them strong delusion, that they should
believe a lie: that they all might be damned who believed not the
truth, but had pleasure in unrighteousness'. 2 Thessalonians 2:9-12
...This symbolism is taken from Daniel... In Revelation 13:14,15 this
refers to something vastly more subtle and much less obvious... all
the accrued wisdom and experience from ages past, together with all
the modern discoveries and technologies, mean that nothing apparent or
crude will be presented, no matter the figurative description...
It is patently obvious that the image of the beast cannot be literal,
because, since it is an image of an admittedly allegorical figure,
literal representation could never be intended. But in a figure the
'image' signifies that ideology which exalts man, establishes world
peace and order under a unified rule, and expresses the concept of
humanity evolving to the pinnacle of his destiny. The image of this -
once shaped by religion - is that of man without the Fall; the world
without condemnation; the earth without the curse; and the future
without the judgment to come. Now, man must surely bow down to that.
...An ideal like that gives new life to humanity, and to human
achievement. This universal concept works: it gives life to its
beliefs, so that the whole of mankind is swept along by the tide of
apparently irresistible achievement. And if any be not conformed, such
aliens as these cannot be fit to live or labour or remain part of
consenting society. John 16:2 & 15:18-19 & James 4:4
The first beast, glorified by the second beast bestows upon the
inhabiters of the earth such social, welfare, medical, technological,
educational, leisure, pleasure, and incremental benefits, that all the
earth defies any who dare to criticize such universal prosperity. Who
dare? A people who hear what the Spirit says... These will neither be
seduced by prosperity, nor coerced by persecution. They have gone
forth outside the camp, bearing his reproach..." The Revelation of
Jesus Christ, John Metcalfe, pages 328-331 extracts, 1998
http://wwwjohnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

Yes, there has been in the past, but will be much more-so in the near future, "a truly alarming outcome for people's non worship of the image of the beast." That is why we have been given the Revelation, which tells us seven times over what to expect and how to be prepared to avoid the global deception; how to avoid the mark of the beast, before our Lord returns.

It will also be a persecution on Christians because the earth beast will ban us from trading lest we have the mark, but in doing this he increases our resolve to hold on for our redemption is at the door!. Upvoted for the step by step breakdown.

@Anne - When I came back on site, it was to check on something other than your A., which I see came at the same time as another upvote for me, so if that was indeed yours, I thank you for that. My next thought was ... Is she siding with me? Sadly, I see that this is not the case. Your often cited "mentor" (if I may be so bold) in quoting 2 Thess, 2: 9-12, has made the mistake, IMHO, of equating the future (unless already now here) Man of Lawlessness with the 2nd beast. But, unlike those true Jesus followers who questioned the PAPACY, it will be the NON Jesus followers who perish.

@OldeEnglish  You asked a good Q, so yes, but I will not engage in an exchange of comments about interpretations, as that is not what comments are for. You may disagree with the author of the book I often quote from, and not up-vote my answer. Having read that 614 book seven times over two years, I have been 'mentored' by that exposition which beats to fiddlesticks all other books / articles I've ever read about 'Revelation' in my +50 years of Bible study. All who do not belong to Jesus will perish when he returns, after Rev.13:15 has happened - 2 distinct events, I suggest.

@Anne - Ah, yes! I had forgotten your reluctance to engage in an exchange of comments, which I fully understand, nevertheless, I still think what I said (in comment to you specifically) needed to be conveyed. We will have to agree to disagree, I guess. Peace be with you. Appreciate your interaction regardless. Sorry that I can't see my way to reciprocate with an upvote, at this time at least.

The book of revelation contains three "beasts":

Beast from the abyss: (Rev 11:7, 12:1-17, 17:8) This beast is the seven-headed dragon, namely the devil or Satan (12:9 & 20:2), of 12:3, who comes from and is thrown back into the abyss (20:3). The fact that this beast is mentioned in 11:7 without further explanation, suggests that it has already been introduced (in 9:1, 11 and 8:12) - a consistent pattern elsewhere in Revelation. A comparison of 12:9, 13 with 8:10, 13, 9:1 - fallen from heaven to earth - lends weight to this view. Isa 14:12 and Eze 28:8, 13-17 records in allegorical form the origin of Satan in heaven, his decent to earth and his ambition to be worshipped like the Most High. See “Satan”.

Beast from the Sea: (Rev 13:1-10) This is Revelation’s most notorious and blasphemous beast whose distinguishing mark is administered by the land beast on the forehead or hand (13:17, 20:4) of the wicked. This beast is the one usually intended when The Beast is mentioned without further explanation (eg, 16:13, 19:20, 20:10 etc). The close parallels between Dan 7 and Rev 13:1-8 strongly suggest the same power. See also “Abomination of Desolation”.

Beast from the Land (or Earth): (Rev 13:11-17) This third beast completes the unholy trinity and is called from the land to help the dragon fight the woman by assisting the sea beast, 12:17, 13:1, 11. In Rev 16:13, 19:20, 20:10, this land beast is also called the false prophet as can be seen by comparing 19:20 with 13:13. As the false prophet, the land beast acts as a counterpoint to the (true) two prophets of 11:10. The land beast is mentioned by name just once - otherwise only by pronoun. The land beast creates a sea beast like organization called the image to the beast that is used to help enforce (under death threat) worship of the sea beast and its image.


That these three beasts form an unholy beast trinity has been noticed by Bible commentators for many centuries.  See the appendix below.
The fulfilment of these prophetic beasts in actual world organizations is, in recent times, become increasingly controversial, mostly because of the variety of prophetic paradigms and sets of presupposition prisms through which people insist upon viewing the apocalypse.  However, most are simple to identify by simply tabulating the precise points of identification and matching them with history.
APPENDIX 1 - Beast Trinity



TRUE (DIVINE) TRINITY
APOSTATE TRINITY of BEASTS




God the Father (the Most High) (Heb 7:1, Acts 7:48, 16:17, etc)
Satan = Beast from the abyss (11:7, 20:1) “like the Most High” (Isa 14:12-14)


is, was, & yet will come (Rev 1:4, 8, 4:8, 11:17)
was, now is not, yet will come (Rev 17:8, 11)


Creator (Ps 33:6, 9, Rev 4:11)
Destroyer (Rev 9:2, 11, 11:7, 8)


Has power and authority (Rev 12:10)
Has power and authority (Rev 13:2)


River of life comes from God (Rev 22:1)
River to kill woman from dragon (Rev 12:15)


**
**


Jesus Christ
Beast from the Sea (13:1-8)


Begins ministry in water (Luke 3:21)
Comes out of water (Rev 13:1)


Has seven horns (Rev 5:6)
Has 10 horns (Rev 13:1)


Jesus like the Father (John 10:30, 14:9)
7 heads & 10 horns like dragon


Slaughtered Lamb (Rev 5:6)
Slaughtered (Rev 13:3)


Miraculously lives (John 11:25, Rom 1:4)
Miraculously lives (Rev 13:3)


Receives throne from Father (Rev 5:7, Matt 28:18)
Receives throne from dragon (Rev 13:2)


Wears a crown (Rev 19:12)
Wears crowns (Rev 13:1)


Jesus’ ministry lasts 3½ years
Beast reigns 42 months (Rev 13:5)


**
**


The Holy Spirit
Beast from the Land (13:11-17)


Spirit like blazing lamps (Rev 4:5, Acts 2, 2 Kings 1:10-12)
Calls fire from heaven (Rev 13:13)


Brings glory to Jesus (John 16:14,15)
Gives glory to sea beast (Rev 13:14)


Gives seal of God (Eph 4:30)
Gives mark of beast (Rev 13:16)


Inspires prophets (2 Pet 1:19-21)
Is the false prophet (Rev 19:20 etc)



Following the battle of Armageddon the Beast Trinity, or Babylon, breaks up into its three parts (Rev 16:19).
Lastly, note that Jesus sends out the three angels of heaven (Rev 14:6-11) to gather people for the great harvest; and the Beast Trinity also sends out three evil spirits to gather people for the great battle of Armageddon

There are some things I would add, but that's a decent breakdown. David Chilton also suggested that just as the church is the image of Christ, so too should the image of the beast be likened to the false church, or synagogue of Satan.

A supplement to the Unholy Trinty theme. In the immediate context of ch13, the first beast has "come from heaven", in that he was expelled from there in ch12. Then the origins of the three beasts can be matched against the tripartite division of the world, "heaven, land and sea", which is one of the recurring formulas of Revelation. It is the division implied in ch12 v12.

@Dottard - I did type a comment to you a couple of hours ago but I guess I didn't add it, in my haste to comment to Stephen. Damn! I'll have to try and recall it but am now fast running out of time. Later ...

While I appreciate yours, not to mention Stephen's answers, I have never been a believer in the "Trinity" (as you very well know), whether it be the holy, or indeed the unholy. Also, you have only made passing reference to the specific "focus" of my question, i.e. the killings of peoples who were not willing to take the "Mark of the Beast". I find it laughable that the first of 2 anonymous "close" votes (neither of which I believe you to be responsible for), gave lack of "focus" for their reasoning, but there we are. As to the rest of my original comment script, I'm drawing a blank. Sorry.

I will offer a brief summary of the view taken in my own book.
In the first place, we shouild note that there are two beasts in ch13. The second beasr is "exercising the authority" of the first one (v12), and in the quoted verse the second beast is setting up the image of the first one. It all hangs on their relationship.
The first beast rises out of the sea (v1). This looks like an echo of Daniel ch7, in which four beasts arise out of the sea, all representing domineering political states. Babylon, the Medo-Persian empire, and Alexander's empire are all recognised in the symbolism. Therefore I take the first beast to represent domineering political power, a state or series of states. This makes it easy to understand how it can "suffer a mortal wound and come back to life". This was the experience of three imperial states in the twentieth century alone. Arguably, Russia did it twice.
My own premise is that the second beast is not just a loudmouth but also the political leader of that state. That would make sense out of "exercises the authority of the first beast in its presence".
There needs to be an historical interpretation, since otherwise John has no message for the persecuted church of his own time, but I would not personally rule out the possibility of a simultaneous message for the future.
Historically, the two beasts would surely be the Roman empire and the emperor. The emperor must receive tokens of worship because he represents the empire. That would be the historical reason why the religious test was applied to suspected Christians, and why refusal of the test would be an act of disloyalty to the empire which would demand the death-penalty.
To see how v15 might work in modern times, one might review the old images of the Nuremberg rallies, understanding the loudmouth Hitler as a "second beast" figure, while the first beast would be the Nazi Reich or the German Volk. We could see Hitler as using the theatrics of those ceremonies to create an "image" of the object of worship which he was presenting to them.
Once we have this "political" understanding of the beasts, it is easy enough, I'm afraid, to understand how dissenters might receive the death-penalty. It is only necessary that another power should become both world-dominating and anti-Christian.

You are right, IMHO, in your assessment of the "sea beast" and how it echoes Daniel 7, but then you run with Russia, which I can't hold with. I do like the idea that you believe my "focus" is most likely warranting historical interpretation and that the Roman Empire (but not the emperor) is at the very least involved, which followed on from the "leopard" analogy, i.e. Greece, but what interests me most, is what followed on from the RE's demise, i.e. the PAPACY, which by many historical accounts took over in 538 AD, only to be subjugated (wounded) in 1798 AD, 1260 yrs later - cf. Rev, 13:5.

@Olde English No, Russia was just an example. Imperial Germany and Imperial China also had mortal wounds and came back to life (Hitler and Mao). I suggest that any resemblance to Imperial Rome would be in dominance and style of government, not in the name or the location (which are red herrings).

I can only assume that by name or the location you are insinuating that my reference to the PAPACY, which was located in Rome, was not far reaching and dominant in their style of government and yet the "death dealing" PAPACY was all of that and more. In fact, many a subsequent, even far-reaching government, was in deference and indeed fearful of same. It took Napoleon to put a "temporary " halt to all that. The two horned beast/false prophet - that of Gt. Britain and the USA - then revived the PAPACY, with a somewhat subdued Image of same, although still to be feared.

Reading the book of Revelation is challenging as it requires a leap of faith to interpret its rich symbolic text and the arrangement of events. Regarding the specific question of whether the event in Revelation 13:15 is historical or futuristic, I believe it is a continuous event. Let me explain:
Firstly, in describing the tribulation of the seven seals (Rev 6-8), seven trumpets (Rev 8-11), and seven bowls (Rev 16), there are interludes that do not seem directly related to the tribulation.

Between the sixth and seventh seal, Revelation 7 describes 144,000 sealed Israelites and a great multitude in white robes from all nations, coming forward to the throne of God, receiving living water, and God wiping away every tear from their eyes. This description is almost identical to Revelation 21, depicting the scene of a New Heaven and a New Earth.

Between the sixth and seventh trumpet, Revelation 10 describes John eating a little scroll, and being told to prophesy again about many peoples, nations, languages and kings (Rev 10:11), likely referring to the Book of Revelation, being translated in different languages worldwide. Revelation 11:1-13 describes the two witnesses, who are the two olive trees and lampstands familiar from Zechariah 4, referring to Zerubbabel and Joshua. The miracles described in Revelation 11:6 were once performed by Elijah and Moses. They are told to prophesy on earth for 1260 days, after which they are killed, paralleling Jesus' ministry on earth for three and a half years.

Between the seven trumpets and the seven bowls, there is a longer interlude from Revelation 12-15. A dragon is described with seven heads, ten horns, and seven crowns on its heads (Rev 12:3). This dragon is identified as Satan (Rev 12:9), who leads the whole world astray. Failing his mission, Revelation 13:1 describes a beast coming out of the sea with seven heads and ten horns, but the crowns are now on its horns. In Revelation 17, a similar beast appears, and an angel explains to John that the seven heads are kings, as well as the ten horns. This suggests the beast's power is dispersed.


Revisiting Revelation 13:15:

The second beast was given power to give breath to the image of the first beast, so that the image could speak and cause all who refused to worship the image to be killed. (NIV)

This scenario is reminiscent of Genesis 2:7, where God breathed life into Adam. Here, Satan mimics God, disguising himself across generations to lead humanity astray. While in ancient time he appeared directly to Eve, he now disperses his power in many forms but continues his deception. Revelation 13:15 may not necessarily mean physical death but implies that those who refuse to comply with these evil entities will endure oppression.

Will have to get to you later. Have not the time right now.

You have given me a lot of info here, with which I am already familiar, but I'm afraid you have hardly answered the question. With regard to the verse in question, I do think physical death is being spoken of, but rather of the past rather than present or future. To say that the verse is really talking about oppression, is to say something other than it actually says.

@OldeEnglish - My thought is that if historically everyone who refused to worship the beast was killed, then Christianity would have ended long ago. There must have been some who survived the penalty. I may not express my thought clearly.

Your point is well taken, so what are we to indeed surmise? The only thing that makes any real sense is that the beast "itself" may well have hidden "itself" within Christianity. See my comment here, presently above, to fellow poster SD, which is a reference to Rev, 13:5 and the 42 months. Year 538 AD was when the "Caesaro-papism" under Roman Emperor Justinian came to a head. Justinian declared himself to be a theologian, much like Constantine before him. Church and state unified, with the PAPACY coming out on top. This aggrandizing paradigm coming to an end thru Napoleon in 1798.

@OldeEnglish - Satan continuously disguises himself in various forms, and this perspective is central to my answer. In Revelation 20:7, when the thousand years are over, Satan is released and once again deceives the nations. The dragon and the beast are metaphors for the many ways Satan disguises himself, they are general terms and not specific to certain historical figures. The crowns or king's title highlight the surreal nature of his power, which persists to this day.

@OldeEnglish - To be more specific, any historical significant figure who led Christianity astray can be considered, in one way or another, a manifestation of Satan. This is not restricted to past events or to individuals who are Christians. His power can afflict any people, as state in Rev 12:9, which says he "leads the whole world astray," for a lasting period until he is bound. After one thousand years, he will do this again, as mentioned in Rev 20:7.
